# How can I send email Headers using Amazon SES?

Tags: email, amazon-ses

I am using a Wrapper from http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-aws-ses/

I am not able to send Email Headers with

```
From: Name <email@example.com>
```

Is there any way we can send headers using amazon ses. Any other PHP Wrapper you recommend which allows us to do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change the FROM Variable to something like this

```
$m->setFrom(" Name <info@gitgrow.com>");
```

Answer (score 7):

For the new API SDK (v2) you can use:

```
$client->sendMail( array(
                   'source' => 'Name <a@b.c>', 
                    ....
                     )
         );
```

Basically if you want to include the name, the source must have the name followed by the email id and importantly, the email id must be enclosed in `<` and `>`